# PHP: krumo() for javascript

Tags: php, javascript, krumo

Is there a javascript version of PHP's `krumo()`? It's really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `console.log()`. If your object is `myObject`, call it like:

```
console.log(myObject);
```

Then open the Javascript console in your browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, etc.) to see the output.

Back in the early days, you needed to install an extension like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), but all modern browsers now include this helpful debugging functionality.

Comment: Besides Firebug, webkit also supports `console.log()` and Chrome's inspector (can't speak for Safari) provides this collapsable representation of an object that Krumo has.

Answer (score 3):

Firebug is one of the best tools to debug JavaScript. You can preview all variable content in addition to debug HTML and css.